# Calling AFNetworking in NSTimer causes serious memory leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks

I'm trying to debug a difficult memory leak. In MyAppDelegate.m, I have

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.notificationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                              target:self
                                                            selector:@selector(syncNotifications:)
                                                            userInfo:nil
                                                             repeats:YES];
    return YES;
}

- (void)syncNotifications:(NSTimer*)timer {
    NSString *path = @"http://example";
    NSLog(@"GET: %@", path);
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *network = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [network GET:path parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"get success");
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

I see memory leaking at the rate of ~1MB / 3 seconds. I've tried setting the network to a property. Also tried commenting out the actual network request as follows:

```
- (void)syncNotifications:(NSTimer*)timer {
    NSString *path = @"http://example";
    NSLog(@"GET: %@", path);
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *network = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
}
```

And while I don't see as much memory leaked, I do still see memory allocations climbing in the Instruments panel. Am I missing something when it comes to memory management for NSTimers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing, I found that the "problem" seemed to be with AFHTTPRequestOperation. I didn't see any "leaks" when switching to the AFHTTPSessionManager.

For more information see:
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2596

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are creating a new instance of `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` every second. The implementation of the `manager` method looks like this:

```
+ (instancetype)manager {
    return [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:nil];
}
```

So if you create the manager once and hold on to it you should be able to fix your memory leak.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that though, setting the manager as a property on the AppDelegate. No luck though.

Comment: @CaptainStiggz That's odd. Well, if you analyze the memory leak with Instruments it should tell you **what** is taking up that memory. Then you'll be able to see who the culprit is.

Comment: Hey thanks again for the input Johannes. I believe there is a memory issue in AFHTTPRequestOperationManager. If you'd like to take a closer look, I posted more details on the problem on [github](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2596).